# What is the most efficient way to integrate qml into Qt Widget applications?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to integrate QML as stated in the question. I want to be able to use data from the C++ side to the QML. Thing is the application itself is a standard QT Widget application, I want to be able to use QML in the UI and be able to send data to it.

I am not expert and I am still learning QT but this is to be integrated into a larger project so at the moment I am testing all this in a "Dummy app". I've watched the playlist made by KDAB that teaches QML but the thing is the GUI itself is composed of the C++ side and QML meaning the usual Design Form in Widget applications was not present.

Comment: I know only one way to integrate QML into QWidget - [QQuickWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickwidget.html#details)

Comment: What I did was indeed using a QQuickWidget in the UI form and in the MainWindow class or Widget class I wrote  ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

I suppose this is the only way

Comment: Yes, if type of `ui->quickWidget` is `QQuickWidget`. Did you have any problem with that?

Comment: No it worked I was saying that's what worked for me eventually. 

The tutorials I saw usually used QML as the main UI without the UI form. So when I tried it like them I had two windows opening one of the Form and one of the QML.

Anyway thanks for responding.

Comment: Actually I would avoid mixing `QWidget` and `QQuick` as much as possible since these are two completely different technologies and potentiality can cause to various kinds of problems, you know ...

Comment: So If I want to design the UI using QML there shouldn't be a UI form and instead work using C++ classes and QML?